# Pointer and memory allocation for the pointee

Tags: c++

I have been struggling with pointer and memory allocation in c for a while.

Here's my implementation for the max subarray problem. It seems to work fine (maybe have bugs). But I have a question about the memory storage for tuple struct object. As you can see, tuple is declared in the global storage. Later in the findMaxSubArray() function, three pointers to Tuple struct are declared. My question is we didn't declare Tuple struct object instances that the pointers (left, right, cross) are addressing how come the pointer dereferences (i.e., left->sum, etc) work. Does the GNU c compiler automatically allocate storage for them? (I don't understand x86 assembly code) Can someone please explain what's going on here? Much appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define NEGINFINITY -2 << 31

typedef struct {
  int lowPosition;
  int highPosition;
  int sum;
} Tuple;

Tuple tuple;

Tuple* findMaxCrossingSubArray(int a[], int low, int mid, int high) {
  int leftSum, rightSum;
  int leftMax, rightMax;
  int sum;

  leftSum = rightSum = NEGINFINITY; 
  sum = 0; 
  for (int i = mid; i >= low; --i) {
    sum += a[i]; 
    if (sum > leftSum) {
      leftSum = sum;
      leftMax = i;
    } 
  }

  sum = 0;
  for (int j = mid + 1; j <= high; ++j) {
    sum += a[j];
    if (sum > rightSum) {
      rightSum = sum;
      rightMax = j;
    }
  }

  tuple.lowPosition = leftMax;
  tuple.highPosition = rightMax;
  tuple.sum = leftSum + rightSum;
  return &tuple;
}

Tuple* findMaxSubArray(int* array, int low, int high) {
  Tuple *left, *right, *cross;
  if (high == low) {
    // base case
    tuple.lowPosition = low;
    tuple.highPosition = high;
    tuple.sum = array[low];
    return &tuple;
  } 
  else {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2; 
    left = findMaxSubArray(array, low, mid);
    right = findMaxSubArray(array, mid + 1, high);
    cross = findMaxCrossingSubArray(array, low, mid, high);

    if (left->sum > right->sum && left->sum > cross->sum)
      return left;
    else if (right->sum > left->sum && right->sum > cross->sum)
      return right;
    else
      return cross;
  }
}

int main() {
  Tuple *result;
  int data[] = {1, -2, 3, 10, -4, 7, 2, -5};
  result = findMaxSubArray(data, 0, 7);
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    cout << data[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
  cout << "The sum of max subarray is " << result->sum 
       << " Starting at index " << result->lowPosition 
       << " ending at index " << result->highPosition << endl;

}
```

Comment: **Does the GNU c compiler automatically allocate storage for them?** Ans: NEVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variable `tuple` is the only actual `Tuple` in this program. Memory for global variables is managed by the compiler.

In `main`, `Tuple *result` is just a pointer which, when you declared it, contains a random number (whatever happened to previously be in the space it now occupies) and thus `result` points to garbage (not a valid `Tuple` object).

Then you assign the result of `findMaxSubArray` to `tuple`. Since `findMaxSubArray` returns `&tuple` (in one way or another) which is a global variable, `result` points to the global variable `tuple`. So when you do `result->sum`, it's the same as doing `tuple.sum`.

In `findMaxSubArray`, the line `Tuple *left, *right, *cross;` declares three pointers to `Tuple`s which contain a garbage value. In one branch of the `if` you don't use them and just return `&tuple`, the address of the global variable `tuple`. In the other branch, you set `left`, `right`, and `cross` to either `findMaxCrossingSubArray` or `findMaxSubArray`, which both return `&tuple` one way or the other.

I do suggest reading a book on C++ and forgetting everything you know about C while using C++ (but remember it all again when you program C again). They are not the same language. This code is riddled with things you learned from your C training (such as `#define` and `typedef struct ... Tuple`) for which C++ offers better facilities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Seth. Like you said, those pointers(left, right and cross) contain garbage data in the first place. Later on, they are assigned to the address of global variable tuple. Since they are pointing to the same memory location, the comparison will end up falling into the else branch which happens to be the right case. If the if condition changes, my implementation will definitely have problem.  I guess I could replace Tuple struct with a class in my implementation. Can you elaborate what are the c++ facilities I can use in my implementation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @itnovice I think that you'd be better served by starting a new question and asking that there.

Answer (score 1):

The only `Tuple` ever actually allocated is the `tuple` at global scope. All the pointers to `Tuple`, e.g. `Tuple* left` just point to that global storage. So for example in:

```
 left = findMaxSubArray(array, low, mid);
 right = findMaxSubArray(array, mid + 1, high);
```

You will find that `left` and `right` both point to the same address and hence have the same pointed to values.

Without working out the detail, and noting that this is C++, not C, you can probably just change the `Tuple*` return types to `Tuple` return by value and work with automatic (stack) storage.

The code becomes something like:

```
Tuple findMaxSubArray(int* array, int low, int high) 
{
  Tuple left, right, cross;
  // blah blah
  if (something)
      return left;
  else
     return right;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, Keith.  Like you have pointed out, left, right and cross are pointing to the same memory location. If we return Tuple by value, the copy constructor will be invoked which introduces some overhead. Can I return Tuple by reference? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of your pointers (left, right, and cross) will always point to same memory location of &tuple.  If you want different tuples you need to use malloc to create different Tuple strucks on the heap.

Comment: Thanks uperez. Yes, all of the pointers are pointing to the same memory location.